# JSpinner Value Not updating

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I Have a JSpinner, which I create and add to the screen, I then update it's value using setValue. If I then call getValue the correct updated value is retuned. yet it doesn't show on the UI and when I click the button to increment it goes to 1 not say 31. I have tried a whole host of GUI updating ideas nothing works.

```
public class test extends JFrame {
private JSpinner jspin;

public test() {
    jspin = new JSpinner();
    this.add(jspin);
    this.setSize(300,300);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new test();
}

public void updateSpin() {
    jspin.setValue(3);
}

}
```

I want the value of the JSpinner to update. Basically in one class () the JSpinner is added to the UI but another class calls a method () which updates it using setValue. which works according to the code, but the UI shows a different story.

Comment: Per the site's FAQ: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Please create and post your [mcve] so we can test your code ourselves.

Comment: Sorry, I can't compile, run or test this code, and so it won't reproduce your problem for me or allow me to guess what could be wrong. Please have a look at the **[mcve]** link one more time to see exactly what I'm requesting.

Comment: Just create a simple class, one with a single JSpinner in a JPanel, and try to write code that reproduces your problem -- in as simple a fashion as possible -- that's what we're looking for.

Comment: I can't recreate it, my logic is fine. When i try to recreate it is works perfectly.

Comment: I beg to differ -- if your logic were fine, then you wouldn't have this problem, this bug. While I can't require you to create an MCVE, I can tell you that it would help you get an answer (if the answer below, my guess, doesn't solve your problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess -- you're correctly calling the `passArgs(...)` method but calling it on the wrong StartUpPane instance, that you **may** be creating a completely new StartUpPane instance, calling this method on it, and expecting the completely separate and unique StartUpPane instance to change, but it doesn't. If this is the case, than a solution is to pass in the correct visualized instance to where it is needed. A better solution is to use the MVC or Model-View-Control structure, and a terrible solution is to use static methods and/or fields.

Another possibility is that you may be shadowing variables, including the one for the StartUpPane -- but who knows.

Again, this is nothing but a silly wild arse guess, or SWAG. Please don't make us guess -- show enough code (but not too much), so we **know** what's going on.